# Is the following equation equivalent to the 2-cocycle condition?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Given a finite **abelian** group $G$, I'm looking for functions $\rho:G \times G \to U(1)$ such that

1)  $~~~~~\rho(g,e) = 1 = \rho(e,g)$, where $e\in G$ is the unit element and such that

2)  $~~~~\rho(a,bc)~ \rho(b,c)~ \rho(b,a) = \rho(b,ac)~ \rho(a,c)~ \rho(a,b)$.

I've noticed that this equation is solved by 2-cocycles of $G$.
Also, the equation is invariant  under 2-coboundaries, i.e. if $\rho$ is a solution, then so is $\rho'(g,h) = \rho(g,h)~\phi(g) \phi(h) \overline{\phi}(gh)$ for any function $\phi:G \to U(1)$.
This makes me suspect that the above equation might be equivalent to the cocycle condition $\rho(a,bc) \rho(b,c) = \rho(ab,c) \rho(a,b)$.

However, I couldn't figure out how to prove this.

**Question:** Is the above equation equivalent to the cocycle equation and if not, has it been studied somewhere and what can be said about its (non-cocyclic) solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in general it's not the case. Morally, I think it can be seen from the fact that your equation only involves product in the second argument of $\rho$ which creates a dissymmetry.

Concretely, consider $G = \mu_3 = \{1,j,j^2\}\subset U(1)$. I define $\rho: G\times G\to U(1)$ by $\rho(1,g)=\rho(g,1)=1$ for all $g\in G$, $\rho(j,j^2)=j$, $\rho(j^2,j)=j^2$, $\rho(j,j)=1$ and $\rho(j^2,j^2)=1$. You can check that this satisfies your condition (unless I made a mistake in my computations).

But it's not a cocycle because $2$-cocycles of *abelian* groups satisfy $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$ (because $2$-coboundaries clearly satisfy this, and any $2$-cocycle in some $A$ becomes a $2$-coboundary in some $B$ such that $A\subset B$).

Comment: That seems to work. Nice counterexample, thank you!